# Erlang - io:format 's result / (formatting with io_lib:format/2)

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to get the result of the output of io:format/1.

I know that there's a similar function in io_lib, io_lib:format/2, but the output is different. In fact, it doesn't do anything at all.
If I try to bound io:format, ok is bounded, and the formatted string is written out to the console.

So my question is, how can I get the same output with io_lib:format/2?
Or how can I bound the formatted string to a variable?

```
1> A = io:get_line('> ').
> "test".
"\"test\".\n"
2> io:format(A).
"test".
ok
3> B = io_lib:format(A, []).
"\"test\".\n"
4> B.
"\"test\".\n"
5> C = io:format(A).
"test".
ok
6> C.
ok
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`io_lib:format` is not an output function the way `io:format` is. Instead `io_lib:format` only returns the value, but does not output it.

The result of `io:format` that you see as "test." is the rendered version as sent to the terminal (including the newline) , then it returns `ok`.  Conversely, the return value of `io_lib:format` that you see as `"\"test\".\n"` is simply the erlang shell's representation of the same string, with the quotes and newline escaped, and surrounded by its own quotes.

`io_lib:format` is more commonly used for inserting values into the strings (similar to C's `printf` functions).  For example, doing something like

```
NewString = io_lib:format("The string entered was ~s I hope you like it",[A])
```

The value of `NewString` would be

```
The string entered was "test".
I hope you like it
```

For which the Erlang Shell's representation would be:

```
"The string entered was \"test\".\n I hope you like it"
```

If all you want to do is output the value you just entered, then `io:format` is sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get the same result as io:format in a variable?
I know it would be easier to use io:read, but I have to use get_line.

Comment: io_lib:format does return the same result as what's sent to io:format. What you see is merely the Erlang shell's representation of the string. `"test".<newline> It looks weird, but that's just because it's escaping the string, and showing you the escapes being used.

Comment: The problem is I can't bound a variable to io:format, because the return value ok is bounded, and the formatted string is simply written out to the console. Is there a simple way to get rid of newlines, like io:format does, or somehow bound the string that is written out?

Comment: io:format *doesn't* actually get rid of the newline, it does as newline does and moves the cursor to the next line, which is "ok" is on the following line. For example, if you just did io:format("1234"), you'd see `1234ok` printed on the line.

Comment: If you just wanted to remove any trailing newline characters, you could do something `string:strip(A,right,10).` 10 being the ASCII number for newline. This just means "If there are any newline character at the end of the string, remove them all"